# MSSQL Subtract two rows from each other in union

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a successful query that shows the first row of last month, and the first row of this month. This query shows fields that have ongoing counters for electricity usage.

I need the difference of a particular field, and then multiply that by .54802 and round to nearest hundredth.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM Datebase
    WHERE DATEPART(M, Timestamp) = DATEPART(M, DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE()))
      AND DATEPART(Yyyy, Timestamp) = DATEPART(Yyyy, DATEADD(M, 0, GETDATE()))
    ORDER BY Timestamp ASC
                          ) AS A
UNION
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM Datebase
    WHERE DATEPART (M, Timestamp) = DATEPART(M, DATEADD(M, 0, GETDATE()))
      AND DATEPART(Yyyy, Timestamp) = DATEPART(YYYY, DATEADD(M, 0, GETDATE()))
    ORDER BY Timestamp ASC
                          ) AS B;
```

This outputs:

```
| ID | Timestamp                | 7000AV119   |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2018-08-01 00:00:03.000  |     3675.59 |
|  2 | 2018-09-01 00:00:03.000  |     3750.93 |
```

I need it to show:

```
| ID | Timestamp                | 7000AV119   | Difference
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 2018-08-01 00:00:03.000  |     3675.59 |     0
|  2 | 2018-09-01 00:00:03.000  |     3750.93 |    41.29
```

Comment: are you sure you want to show 2 rows in output ?what is the purpose of showng 2 rows ?You can show one row as output and desire result.

Comment: In reality I just need the end value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the two records as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(timestamp), month(timestamp) order by timestamp asc) as seqnum
      from Datebase t
      where timestamp >= dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -2))
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Then I would use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       round(([7000AV119] - lag([7000AV119]) over (order by timestamp)
             ) * 0.54802,
             2
            )
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(timestamp), month(timestamp) order by timestamp asc) as seqnum
      from Datebase t
      where timestamp >= dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate(), -2))
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns `NULL` rather than `0` for the first row.  That makes more sense to me.

Comment: I don't see where you put lag at all?

And I get an error if I keep t.* 

I'm quite new to sql.

Comment: @user8465543 . . . The code has `lag()`.  I'm not sure what your error is.

Comment: Apologies, yours is correct. 

I forgot that the column type is sql_variant (annoying from software installation). I converted the type to int, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with lag function

```
with testcte as
(
select *

 from (select top(1) * from DATABASE

  WHERE DATEPART(m, Timestamp) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, Timestamp) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
 order by Timestamp ASC)  a

union

select * 

from (select top(1) * from DATABASE 
WHERE DATEPART(m, Timestamp) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, Timestamp) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
 order by Timestamp ASC) b
)

select id,Timestamp,7000AV119,7000AV119- LAG(7000AV119,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS Diff
from testcte
```

Comment: I get 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '-'.